# SVM CV error decreases with number of features increased, but it's overfit. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm using RBF-kernel libsvm for classification task. 
My dataset is about 700 vectors, quite inbalanced, about 20%positive:80%negative.

I use several feature rating algotithms, such as boruta or fselect.py from libsvm to build ranged feature raiting list, then select some top features from this list.

I use repeated (about 20 times) 10-fold CV for SVM parameters C & G search. The error estimated by area-under-curve(AUC) value for ROC curve.

The problem is, when I take more features, AUC value get quite high (the more features, the bigger AUC value, more than 0.95), but test error increased at some point i.e. it's overfit with big number of features!

The optimal number of features lies somwhere in the middle (about 30 in my case).

Increasing number of repeats or folds in CV does not help much

How can I avoid this? 
I expect that properly implemented CV always gives good regularization results regardles of number of features, i.e., it should give small AUC values with big number of features.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-validation has nothing to do with overfitting and cannot make your model generalize to unseen data. Instead, it **may** give you an estimation of how your model performs with new and unseen data. Therefore, do not expect much improvement in your test accuracy by implementing cross-validation or changing the number of folds.
The answer to your question lies in a basic intuition about machine learning: The more features you have, the more data you need to train a good model. If your model takes many features as input but lacks enough data for training, it won't be able to generalize and perform very well regardless of how well it is implemented.

Now, some suggestions:

- If the performance with the optimal number of features (about 30 as you stated) is good enough, stick with it.
- If you need better performance and believe the poor performance is due to the low number of features, try other feature reduction techniques such as Principal Component Analysis to reduce the number of features while maintaining their useful data as much as possible.
- If none of the above methods work well, try other classification algorithms to find the best one.

Comment: Well, according to this: https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning and many other sources, CV is a method to prevent overfitting: "Cross-validation is a powerful preventative measure against overfitting".    I forgot to mention: the number of support vectors among all features sets (from 20 to 100) stays almost the same: about 30% of size of data set.  So, it means degree of generalization is the same among models.  So, how can I improve CV to get it more consistent with test?